# centos 7 ModSecurity: Error reading request body

Tags: linux, centos

What is this error 
ModSecurity: Error reading request body: Software caused connection abort [hostname "sub.domain.com"] [uri "/img/logo.jpg"] [unique_id "XYFUZFaf2KWetx76xEFo3QAAAAE"]

Answer (score 1):

this is not easy to answer with the amount of information that you are providing in your question.

In general, you can think of ModSecurity as a filter software that checks - in this case - incoming HTTP requests. Being an application level check it waits until it has received the entire HTTP request, and this is where it fails with the error message you list above, because somehow the TCP connection transporting the request has be terminated.

So a couple of details that could help finding the source of the problem:

a) Do you know which is the HTTP client (Chrome, FF, a program)? Looking at the HTTP headers in the request packet/data stream could help you figure this out

b) What kind of application are you running on the server? According to google search results, this error seems to be reported mainly by people running a web shop in some kind of hosting environment.

c) Digging deeper in ModSecurity documentation should reveal whether the "Software" referred to in the error message can be pinpointed more precisely by e.g. increasing the logging level of the ModSecurity module.

Hope this helps...